# Match values across rows and make them blank as per situation

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset .

```
    input acct_num test_id dispute_amount transac_amount tran_key cummu_tran_amt ;
    DATALINES; 
    55203610 1 50  40 123 40
    55203610 1 50  10 124 50
    55203610 1 50  30 125 80
    55203610 2 60  40 123 40   
    55203610 2 60  10 124 50
    55203610 2 60  30 125 80
    ;
    run;
```

It has dispute amount which has to be matched with transac_amount , if the cumulative sum of transac_amount is less or equal to dispute amount the transact amount has to be made 0. This logic has to built based on test_id. Also if the cumulative sum become larger than the dispute amount an overage field has to be created , which contains the difference.

Dataset that I want.

```
    input acct_num test_id disute_amount transac_amount tran_key overage;
    DATALINES; 
    55203610 1 50  0  123  0
    55203610 1 50  0  124  0
    55203610 1 50  30 125  0
    55203610 2 60  0  123  0 
    55203610 2 60  0  124  0
    55203610 2 60  30 125 20
    ;
    run;
```

I have used nested loops for counter this but to no avail, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the dispute_amount is constant through each test_id, correct?

Comment: @draycut - yes its constant

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
data have;
input acct_num test_id dispute_amount transac_amount tran_key ;
DATALINES; 
55203610 1 50  40 123 
55203610 1 50  10 124 
55203610 1 50  30 125 
55203610 2 60  40 123 
55203610 2 60  10 124 
55203610 2 60  30 125 
;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   by test_id;
   if first.test_id then cummu_tran_amt = 0;
   overage = 0;

   cummu_tran_amt + transac_amount;

   if cummu_tran_amt <= dispute_amount then transac_amount = 0;
   else overage = cummu_tran_amt - dispute_amount;
run;
```

Comment: This did not work

Comment: the code produces exactly your desired result besides the overage in the thirs obs of your want data set, which I assume is a typo . Please explain exactly what 'did not work'